# Fresh Install WP & Civi - Undefined Array Key Warnings Everywhere

Tags: wordpress, error, installation, install

Latest Civi and WP - PHP 8 - Database is utf8mb4 and utf8mb4_unicode_ci

I am getting these Undefined Array Key Warnings everywhere. Did I set up the database incorrectly or could it be something else?

Examples:

Warning: Undefined array key "email" in /home/prinyc/www/www/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/templates_c/en_US/%%6F/6F7/6F7BB438%%Contribution.tpl.php on line 42

Warning: Undefined array key "parseStreetAddress" in /home/prinyc/www/www/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/templates_c/en_US/%%05/056/056C19FD%%street_address.tpl.php on line 23

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

php8 is more noisy so that's part of it. Also your php.ini error_reporting is probably E_ALL, and you might even have WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY turned on (https://codex.wordpress.org/WP_DEBUG)

The install itself is probably fine, it's just that civi has tons of old code that needs bringing up to date and it's time-consuming to do that and to get it reviewed, so it happens slowly.

Comment: Thank you, we decided to downgrade to 7.4 for now, no need to be on 8.0 - all the errors are gone now.

Comment: Unfortunately support for PHP 7.4 will end on 28 Nov 2022. So there will be a need to be on 8.0.

Comment: @Demerit Is there an CiviCRM official statement or at least an issue about those warnings? We don't want to change the error reporting level, because otherwise we might not notice "real" problematic warnings.

Comment: I can't speak for CiviCRM LLC, I can just repeat what I wrote that "civi has tons of old code that needs bringing up to date and it's time-consuming to do that and to get it reviewed, so it happens slowly". If people are able to fund someone to do the code changes and then get someone to review those changes, that would help speed it up. The initial lab ticket was https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/2201#note_68029.